# How to set values of global variable inside inner interface and use the values outside of the interface in adnroid

Tags: interface

Is there any way to set value of global variable inside an interface and use the value outside of it?

Here is sample of my code:

```
class A{
static ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    get(new Inter() {
        @Override
        public void callBack(ArrayList<String> list) {
            myList = list; // here list is the textual data from firebase and I want to use it outside
            //  this get function call
        }
    });
    myList.toString(); // I want to use it here. But its value out of the function call was null
                       // but it has the same value with list inside the function call
}
static void get(Inter inter){
    // here I want to get some textual data from firebase into ArrayList of String
    list = array of String from firebase
    inter.callBack(list);
}
interface Inter{
    void callBack(ArrayList<String> list);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the list directly after the `get()` call, because the get call is async and has not yet finished.
You can create a method outside the interface that takes the list as a parameter:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    get(new Inter() {
        @Override
        public void callBack(ArrayList<String> list) {
            doSomethingWithList(list);
        }
    });
    
}

private static void doSomethingWithList(List<Sting> list){
    //you code here
}
```

Or you can use method-reference:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    get(<your class>::doSomethingWithList);
}

private static void doSomethingWithList(List<Sting> list){
    //you code here
}
```